# Javascript inserting text not working server side

Tags: javascript, text, server-side, client-side

I'm very new to Javascript. So as an exercise, I wanted to create a script, which creates automatically accounts. As I found out, the text is just client sided! Is there any way to fix that problem?

**The Code(only the important Part):**

```
var TheTextBox = document.getElementById("top-register-email");
TheTextBox.value = TheTextBox.value + rndmail;
var TheTextBox = document.getElementById("top-register-nickname");
TheTextBox.value = TheTextBox.value + rndname;  
var TheTextBox = document.getElementById("top-register-password");
TheTextBox.value = TheTextBox.value + rndpw;
```

EDIT:
The Site I want to do this is not my own Site. I'm not trying to act like a human!

Comment: You should probably add more detail to this.  I'm not sure what you actually want.  You say you want to automatically create accounts - are you trying to do this on a site that isn't your own?  Like you're replicating a human signing up?

Comment: @Flojomojo: On the contrary, you may want to go ahead and post that HTML code because it will help answer several questions. Is `.register` the classname of a form submit button? If so, you need to assign values to the inputs *before* you post the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to the world of Client+Server development.

You will have to send your data back to the server so that the server can commit it to your storage mechanism.

**That** will take a lot more information before we can really be helpful.

I would recommend finding a good tutorial on client/server development for the web.

To summarize the problem you're facing: you are really needing two "applications".  One is the web page that gathers/displays information, and the other is the server which stores/retrieves data.

This is, of course, a VERY simplified explanation of the way things work.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your fast anwser! Ok i try to find a good video and hopefully im going to be able to do this!

Comment: I'm sure you will.  It's just learning curve.  I'd recommend Node.js because it's javascript, and because I like it.